# Access to method of a class which is private member of another class

Tags: c++

I found a topic with similar question but privacy whas not issue in that case and I still can't find a good answer.

I've got 2 classes

```
class member_class{
  string data
  public:
  void edit_data();
};
class Foo{
  member_Class member;
};
```

How do i call function edit_data when I got objcect of class Foo? Should I make "member" public or is there another solution? I thought about it and the only solution i could invent is to make method in Foo class which only job is to call member.edit_data() function but it seems silly, because I should write such a function for every method of member_class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could make a getter in `Foo` to get `member`.

Comment: If you want to call this function from outside the Foo but not from inside, why put it inside a member class?

Comment: @zenith you mean like member_class & {return &member;}? I think it can solve the problem, is it the best way to do it?

Comment: @Modelowy Depends on whether it's a good design decision in your case. We can't know because you didn't tell us what you're *actually* trying to do, you only gave meaningless class and function names. If you want us to be able to help you with your actual problem you need to be *specific*. Right now we can't even know whether two separate classes is actually the best way to do what you want.

Comment: @zenith i gave this general description because i thought i is more common problem. Thanks for your help, I think I should rethink classes in my project.